# Fundamental question about Arquillian for remote testing

Tags: dependency-injection, cdi, jboss-weld, jboss-arquillian

I've recently started learning about Arquillian. Was following the Geting started tutorial, learned about "Container Varieties" that talks about Remote, Embedded and Managed containers.I'm bit confused about how Arqillian treats these different varieties.

My question is: The Getting started tutorial first example (that has TemparatureConverter) uses JBoss AS 6 as Remote container.  What i understood is that my main application archive that contains the TemparatureConverter bean will be deployed in JBoss AS 6 (that is running in its own VM) and my Test class will run in a separate VM.

I added some log messages to TemparatureConverter.java i.e. Bean class:

```
public double convertToCelsius(double f) {
    System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@Inside container: convertToCelsius");
    return ((f - 32) * 5 / 9);
}

public double convertToFarenheit(double c) {
    System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@Inside container: convertToFarenheit");       
    return ((c * 9 / 5) + 32);
}
```

I also added some log messages to my Test class:

```
@Test
    public void testConvertToCelsius() {
        System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@Inside Junit client");
        Assert.assertEquals(converter.convertToCelsius(32d), 0d);
        Assert.assertEquals(converter.convertToCelsius(212d), 100d);
    }
```

Now I started JBoss AS and run the test cases through command line by typing: `mvn test -Pjbossas-remote-6`

I was thinking that log messages that I added in Bean class will be printed on JBoss console, and the log messages that I added in my Test class will be printed on Maven console window, because these two things are running in separate VM.

However that did not happen, and I saw all the log messages are getting printed on JBoss AS console.

That means, my Test cases are running inside JBoss AS container along with the Bean class.

If this is true, then where is remoteness here? I mean, both the test case and bean are running inside same JVM. This is similar to "embedded container" behaviour, isn't?

I'm referring this explanation:

```
a remote container resides in a separate JVM from the test runner; Arquillian binds to the container to deploy and undeploy the test archive and invokes tests via a remote protocol (typically HTTP)
```

But in this case, it appears Arquillian is placing my Test cases along with Bean class in same JVM.

Let me know, if my question is not clear?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Arquillian is deploying your test case classes along with the code that is being tested in your target container.

To quote the docs:

> Arquillian packages the ShrinkWrap-defined archive at runtime and deploys it to the target container. It then **negotiates** the execution of the test methods and captures the test results using remote communication with the server.

So in terms of "remoteness", what Arquillian provides is a way to initiate the test "remotely" and have the result presented to the developer as if it was run "locally". The sales pitch being that you should not have to care about deployment and you're able to run test in your own development environment.

The difference in remote and embedded containers then becomes the way the container is run. Remote means that you have a container running alongside your development environment before the test is run. And embedded adds the value of only having a container running when the test is started.